# Inconsistent results of stored procedure execution - ASP.net code vs Direct SP call

Tags: asp.net, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

Thanks in advance for anyone's help. This is mystery which is driving me crazyyyy :(.

IF I run this following stored procedure directly on SQL server 2008R2, it returns the desired rows. But if I call this via ASP.net(3.5) it returns empty data from the last Select statement in SP.

Is there any scoping involved in this regarding the temp table @_CalendarDate?

Stored Procedure:

```
USE[DB]

GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


ALTER PROCEDURE [WC].[spsGetDayCyclePeriod]
(
    @Param_StartDate datetime,
    @NumberOfDayRange int,
    @Campus_Type varchar(2)
)
AS

DECLARE @DateRangeStart datetime
DECLARE @DateRangeEnd datetime
DECLARE @_CalendarDate TABLE (CollegeDate datetime)

BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SET DATEFIRST 1

SELECT @DateRangeStart=max(CalendarDate) FROM [X].dbo.CalendarEvents 
    WHERE CalendarDate <= @Param_StartDate and left(CalendarType,1)= @Campus_Type 
    and  (CalendarType <> @Campus_Type+'_H' and  CalendarType<>'H'
    and convert(INT, right(CalendarType, len(CalendarType)-3))>0)

    SELECT @DateRangeEnd=min(CalendarDate) FROM [X].dbo.CalendarEvents 
    WHERE CalendarDate >= dateadd(day, @NumberOfDayRange-1, @Param_StartDate) 
    and left(CalendarType,1)= @Campus_Type and  (CalendarType <> @Campus_Type+'_H'
    and  CalendarType<>'H' and convert(INT, right(CalendarType, len(CalendarType)-3))=0)


    --Get all Dates within range
    ;WITH CollegeDate AS
    (
        SELECT @DateRangeStart AS DateValue
        union all
        SELECT dateadd(day, 1, DateValue)
        FROM    CollegeDate   
        WHERE   dateadd(day, 1, DateValue) <= @DateRangeEnd
    )
    INSERT INTO @_CalendarDate (CollegeDate)
    SELECT DateValue FROM CollegeDate OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)



SELECT  * from @_CalendarDate

END
```

ASP.Net code:

```
DataTable dayCycle = new DataTable();
            var dateTimestr = startDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("WC.spsGetDayCyclePeriod", new SqlConnection(Connection)))
            {
                sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                var range = endDate.Subtract(startDate).Days;
                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Param_StartDate", dateTimestr));
                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@NumberOfDayRange", range));
                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Campus_Type", campus));
                //dayCycle = SqlHelper.GetDataTableUsingSqlCommand(sqlCommand);

                try
                {
                    SqlDataAdapter _dap = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);

                    _dap.Fill(dayCycle);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                { throw new Exception(ex.ToString()); }

                return dayCycle;
```

Comment: Not sure if this could be the solution, so I post as comment, but I will try to define explicitily the datatype and size for the @campus_type parameter. It is possible that will be passed as a NVARCHAR instead of VARCHAR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for help.

Solved the problem myself ! Hopefully it will help someone else as well in future. Here is the answer:

In above ASP.net code:

```
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Campus_Type", campus));
```

**campus** is a enum type and when I was calling the above method with enum type I was actually passing the int value instead of string. So this is what I change to. This was confusing because when I was debugging my code I was using cursor on top of the @campus which basically calls toString so I was seeing the right value (which was wrong) the actual value was passed was number of enum.

```
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Campus_Type", campus.ToString()));
```

**And the above change solved the problem.**

What I learned from this is Always...Always confirm that the arguments you intend to pass to SP is what SP is receiving so retrieve back your passed arguments by running the following before you do anything with Stored procedures...

```
Select @Your_Param1, @Your_Param2
```

And then check on code side that you are receiving what you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Pass @Param_StartDate as a date time object rather than a string.